# .Net Core 2 Routing without MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to create a simple .Net Core 2 application with an Angular front end and an api/db backend.

I do not want to use MVC, since I have no need for typical dot net Views or Models, but I am having trouble serving my index.html files and also routing the api calls to my controller.

I know it's somewhere in the program.cs and involving the routes, but I have been having trouble finding documentation on how to do what I want without using the mvc package.

Simply, here are my requirements again:

1. Serve my angular index.html file when routing to the root (let angular handle the rest of the routes there)

   2. Route my /api routes to be routed to a c# dot net controller
   3. Not to use MVC

Thanks!

Comment: In .NET Core 2.0, Web API and MVC have been merged into a single framework called MVC. So, you are in fact looking for MVC if you want to add API routes.

Comment: I understand. Would you maybe be able to provide me with an example of how just to serve an html file though? For instance, in order to serve my angular app, I don't want to have to route to the controller action and return the view. I shouldn't need a controller action, right?

Comment: I believe all you would need is `app.UseStaticFiles()`.

Comment: But what is the code in the routes to have routes like "...com/" and "...com/about/" serve the index.html file and pass the route to the angular router?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the the `UseRouter()` middleware to explicitly map routes directly as part of your application configuration pipeline.

For example, the following creates a custom route to handle Lets Encrypt requests which by default would fail if any other routing is enabled. The following code goes into the `Configure()` method of the server's `Startup` class:

```
        // Handle Lets Encrypt Route(before MVC processing!)
        app.UseRouter(r =>
        {
            r.MapGet(".well-known/acme-challenge/{id}", async (request, response, routeData) =>
            {
                var id = routeData.Values["id"] as string;
                var file = Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, ".well-known", "acme-challenge", id);
                await response.SendFileAsync(file);
            });
        });
```

This essentialy makes it very easy to simple routing scenarios or forward requests to other handlers.

Note that this is a **raw interface** that doesn't include any input or output handling beyond the raw Request/Response semantics.

If you are doing anything with API style data, then I would still recommend using MVC and controllers which handle all sorts of things that you'd otherwise have to build yourself. In Core, API and MVC run the same Controller pipeline so you can think of MVC as Web API and MVC combined.

For most common use cases using MVC is still the way to go. The above approach is great for micro-services or one off requests as that might buy you a little bit of a performance gain since it doesn't have to load any of the MVC bits or fire into that pipeline, but you're responsible for doing your own serialization and request processing.

Comment: So I should still just use a controller method and return my index.html through that instead, correct?

Comment: For index.html and similar items use the StaticFile middleware. It'll handle some minimal level of caching and deals with content types and expirations properly.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can always activate MVC using `.AddMvcCore()` and turn on the JSON formatter (I'm assuming your API will be JSON) using `.AddJsonFormatters()`.

In this scenario, you'll inherit from `ControllerBase` instead of `Controller`.

Provided you have static files enabled, you can just place the `index.html` in the top-level of your webroot (`wwwroot`) and it will be served as the default document. Your Angular app will take over from their, interoping with the API you've built on the backend.